# utopia mathdesign and biber incompatibility

Tags: biblatex, xetex, fontspec, biber, input-encodings

I have a problem using utopia fonts with xltxtra and biber when using non-ascii characters. The problem disappears if using computer-modern (off-shelf LaTeX) or bibtex instead of biber.  Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biberUTF8test.bib}
\begin{document}
  \citet{Babuska:73:article:The-finite} is not ascii.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

where the biberUTF8test.bib is

```
@article{Babuska:73:article:The-finite,
  Author = {Ivo Babuška},
  Doi = {10.1007/BF01436561},
  Fjournal = {{Numerische Mathematik}},
  Issn = {0029-599X; 0945-3245/e},
  Journal = {Numer. Math.},
  Language = {English},
  Msc2010 = {65N30 65N15 35J20},
  Pages = {179--192},
  Publisher = {Springer-Verlag, Berlin},
  Title = {The finite element method with {Lagrangian} multipliers.},
  Volume = {20},
  Year = {1973}}
```

running `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex` fails to show the š in the author's name, but

commenting the third line in the first file and running same sequence works

or

replacing biber by bibtex in the fourth line of first file and same sequence also works

Any clue someone?  Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It doesn't make much sense to use `mathdesign` with XeLaTeX. Just do `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead of `xltxtra` and compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: If you simply add a `š` to your source you'll see the same issue, BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fonts used by `mathdesign` are not compatible with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`, because they're neither OpenType nor TrueType fonts.

Replace `\usepackage{xltxtra}` with

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and compile with `pdflatex`.

[image]